# React Slider Issue when I try to automate with useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-satoshi-l38sg?file=/src/Hero.js:970-1092

So I made a basic image slider in react that has a next and prev function to change slides manually. My issue is when I try to automate the slides using setTimeout, I run into issues.

Here is my code

```
    const Section = ({ slides }) => {
        const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
        const length = slides.length;

        useEffect(() => {
          setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);

          return function() {
            clearTimeout(nextSlide);
          };
        });

        const nextSlide = () => {
          setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
        };

        const prevSlide = () => {
          setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
        };

        if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
          return null;
        }
```

So if I just add an onClick function to my arrow `onClick={prevSlide}` or `onClick={nextSlide}` it seems to work completely fine manually clicking the arrow buttons and changing the images.

But when I tried to add the useEffect(), it starts working normal at first, but the moment I click on the next button it starts to increase in speed until it is changing slides super fast. It looks like every time I click the next button it triggers the useEffect again and basically it's restarting with every click

This is the code I am referring to

```
         useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);

      return function() {
        clearTimeout(nextSlide);
      };
    });
```

I don't know how to refactor my setTimeout to work with my current functions. I know it's only using the nextSlide, but how would I write a function that works for both prev and next buttons and doesn't rerender the function whenever I click manually on the arrow buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `useEffect` without a dependancy array that means it will run in every render, don't think that is what you would need exactly in this situation. First thing you would have to add `count` inside `useEffect` dependancies, and you may bring the `nextSlide` function inside the hook. Since using functions as dependencies and adding them inside dependency arrays beat the purpose of adding them in the first place, due to that fact that functions get re-declared every time your functional component re-renders. Two solutions for this issue, either wrap your `nextSlide` in `useCallback` and use it inside the effect. (you may safely omit it as a dependancy from dep.array). or declare `nextSlide` inside the hook itself.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent((current) => (current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1));
  };

 //rest...

}, [current]);
```

the other issue you might face when setting timeouts is that you have to be mindful about clearing them, specially in this kind of use case.  The weird behavior of the slides moving back and forth or unexpectedly when you click the prev, next buttons is partly because of this. When you click previous, there might be a setTimout underway, operating on a previous `current` that is about to execute right at that moment. When that happens, instead of going backwards when `prev` is clicked the slider might go forwards. A solution could be to have a reference to the setTimeout in a `ref` (`useRef` in funcitonal comp.) and clear it every time you manually click the buttons.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const nextSlide = () => {
      setCurrent((current) => (current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1));
    };

    timeout.current = setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);

    return function () {
      if (timeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
      }
    };
   }, [current, length]);
```

`nextSlide`, `prevSlide` functions will be like,

```
  const timeout = useRef(null);

  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (timeout.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    if (timeout.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };
```

**Sandbox :** https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-https-qqsof?file=/src/Hero.js:768-1123

Comment: ah this is perfect! thanks. Do you happen to know how I would add an opacity effect, so everytime the slide switches it has like a mini animation effect? I tried following a tutorial and they used something like this `opacity: ${({ current }) => (current ? '1' : '0')}; 
  transition-duration: 10s ease; ` but for my it doesn't work

Comment: @Johnxr look into react transition group https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Comment: also do approve and up-vote the answer if it solved the issue in your question. @Johnxr

Comment: one thing on my site it said `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'length'.` so does adding it into the useEffect array solve that issue properly? that's what I did and the error went away, but not sure if that's the correct way to fix that error

Comment: ah, yeah you can safely pass the length variable into dependancy array, after current, `[current , length]` like so. Since it doesn't change it does matter. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with `useEffect`.

Your implementation just runs the code every state changes happens.

Try including an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const slider = setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);

  return function() {
    clearTimeout(slider);
  };
}, []);
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: if I add that, I get this error `line 71:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'nextSlide'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`. Then if I add [nextSlide] I get this error after `Line 56:9:  The 'nextSlide' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 73) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'nextSlide' in its own useCallback() Hook`

Comment: Are you trying to automate only one step through useEffect ?

Comment: nah I just only put nextSlide cause I didn't know how to implement both prev and next buttons in my useEffect. I just need a function that can automate the slides + allow me to click next or prev without rendering things with each click.

Comment: Can you share your slider implementation ? And prev and next button functionality should not go in useEffect. You should be careful in using useEffect as you can run into infinite loop. Just the 2 cents.

Comment: I think you might need to define the `nextSlide` inside the useEffect,

Comment: ```useEffect(() => {
   const nextSlide = () => setCurrent((currentVal) => currentVal === length - 1 ? 0 : currentVal + 1);

  const slider = setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);

  return function() {
    clearTimeout(slider);
  };
}, []); ```

Comment: @Anuja that would cause issues because I also have a prevSlide function that needs to be addressed

Comment: @Johnxr why would you call the `prevSlide` from the hook ? i assume your slider only moves in forward direction only. Even if you wanted to use `preSlide` inside the effect hook, just define is inside the hook the same way. or else another option is to wrap outside `prevSlide` `nextSlide` in `useCallback` and use them inside hook. then you can safely omit them from dependancy array.

Comment: @Anuja I have a prev button and next button. And I see I guess it should only move next, but still my issue is when use your function, it only switched to the next slide then stops. So not sure why it doesn't loop through all the slides infinitely.

Comment: @Johnxr add a codesandbox to your question, then I'll answer.

Comment: @Anuja check above I added it to question. Notice that when you click next button multiple times, the slides switch faster and faster and you can see it in the console.log.

Comment: @kay I added a codesandbox to my question

Comment: @Johnxr check answer